# How to know if field is masked due to field level security?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

is there a way to find out if field level security has been applied to a field in DCRM 2013?

I'm looking for something like:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("controlName").isMasked()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attributeName").getUserPrivilege()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_getUserPrivilege), which returns an object containing three booleans:

- *canRead*
- *canUpdate*
- *canCreate*

In your case you could check the value of .*canRead* to figure out whether the user can see the contents of the field or not.